# WPF проверка значений

Tags: wpf, валидация

Есть два изсестных мне подхода проверки вводимых данных и выдачи соотвествующего сообщения пользователю - это генерация исключения в сеттере и использование `ExceptionValidationRule` и использование интерфейса `IDataError`.

Вопрос в следующем: можно ли применять разные стили `ErrorTemplate` в зависимости от типа исключения?

Приведу пример - есть класс описывающий объект, с полями `A`, `B` и `C`. В зависимости от занчений `A` и `B` поле `C` может быть либо обязательным, либо желательным. В первом случае незаполненость поля `C` - это критическая ошибка и нельзя давать пользователю сохранить объект, во втором же случае нужно просто уведомить пользователя.

На деле же я хочу применять разные стили в зависимости от того желательное поле или обязательное для заполнения. Скажем для обязательных подсвечивать контролы красным, а для желательных - зеленым. Возможно ли это, или придется придумать другой подход, без использованяи встроенной валидации?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Ответа не знаю, подписался на обновления, может, кто напишет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем решение нашлось в ходе изучения структуры класса [`Validation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.validation(v=vs.110).aspx). Почему я его так долго искал - не знаю, не туда смотрел видимо.

У класса [`Validation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.validation(v=vs.110).aspx) есть коллекция [`Errors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errors(v=vs.110).aspx), которая содержит описание ошибок валидации. Дак вот каждый элемент этой коллекции имеет тип [`ValidationError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.validationerror(v=vs.110).aspx), у которого и есть нужное нам свойство `Exception`. Теперь мы можем основываясь на его типе, определять шаблон.

Приведу пример. Может кому пригодится.

Есть простой класс:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public int A { get; set; }

   public int B { get; set; }

   private int _c;
   public int C
   {
      get { return _c; }
      set
      {
         // Вот тут мы и будем в зависимости от состояния других полей генерировать разные исключения
         if (A == 0 && B == 0 && value == 0)
            throw new ArgumentMandatoryException("Поле является обязательным к заполнению");
         if ((A != 0 || B != 0) && value == 0)
            throw new ArgumentDesiredException("Поле является желательным к заполнению");
         _c = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Как видите в сеттере свойства `C` мы в зависимости от выполнения условия бросили два разных исключения. Теперь нам надо обработать это в шаблоне [`Validation.ErrorTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate(v=vs.90).aspx). Здесь нам помогут `ContentControl` и `DataTemplate`. Получим что-то такое:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ArgumentMandatoryException}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ArgumentDesiredException}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="errorTemplate" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].Exception}"></ContentControl>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="myControl" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Теперь в зависимости от типа исключения рамка будет либо класной, либо желтой.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший пример.

Comment: @VladD, всегда пожалуйста!:)