# Вывод результата валидации контрола

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь сделать валидацию для `TextBox`. Проблема в том что сообщение с информацией для пользователя вылазит на соседний контрол. Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы оно отобразилось не внизу, а вверху, а так же сменить его цвет?

```
public class LoginVm : VmBase
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(32, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Xaml

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1"
         FontFamily="Comic Sans MC"
         Text="{Binding Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
         FontSize="25">
      <TextBox.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20">Email</TextBlock>
      </TextBox.ToolTip>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное, дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/309848/10105

Comment: @VladD, Да, думаю разберусь. Спасибо.

Comment: Тогда пока не закрываем, разбирайтесь и отпишитесь о результатах.